# Netbeans JAX-WS client - encoding error

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, ant, jax-ws

I'm developing a web service client JAVA (JDK 1.6)  with JAX-WS API on netbeans ide (8.0.2) .

J2EE container is JBoss 4.2.1 and I've followed the official netbeans guide to create a web service client with JAX-WS ([guide](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html)).

When I tried to import the WSDL, IDE returns this error:

```
/Users/xxxxx/NetBeansProjects/XXXX/DCS_XXX/nbproject/jaxws-build.xml:45: class com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport2 doesn't support the "encoding" attribute.
```

---

Thanks

Comment: What `jaxb.encoding` do you use? Default = `UTF-8`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue , I deleted and re-imported web service still it did not work. So i just deleted `encoding="${source.encoding}"` from `Jaxws-build.xml` it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, using the same java and netbeans version.

I don't know what coused this error, but suddenly it started working. I have no explanation why.

My steps were as follows:
1)Deleted corrupted WS client
2)Created new "Web service from wsdl"
3)Deleted this web service
4)Created new WS Client.

I was monitoring the jaxws-build.xml file, and i have no idea why the "enconding" attribute was there. Now its gone and the client is working.